# Get Position from OnTouchEvent

Tags: android, ontouch

I used on touch event to find the touched position by the user.I used the following code

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              float x=event.getX();
              float y=event.getY();

              Log.d("MULTIPLE", "X=" + x + " Y=" + y);
         }
        return true;
     }
```

And according to the position some methods are called.

When i tested in different devices the x and y values changed.Is there any way to get a unique value for x and y across all devices

Comment: X & Y value will differ based on the touch location. Chances are good that you touched different pixels on both the devices.

Comment: What do you mean in "values changed"? You get coords inside your view and you have coords in pixels. Different devices have different screen resolution and density.

Comment: X and Y value changes when i Touch on same position on different devices.Thats i meant

Comment: @Sunny post which devices you use, what values you get, What you screen looks like

Comment: @Demand I got almost same location on Tab2 and Galaxy S.But it changes in Galaxy S5 in large way.I think the screen density is the reason.Right?

Comment: I think yes. Do you understand what is screen density and how it works? In common case, simply divide position to screen density.

Comment: @Demand I tried that.:(

Comment: Ok, edit your question. Add more information, what are you doing, where you touch, what you get and what you expect to get. I have no time to ask you tons of question to understand what problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55351/discussion-between-sunny-and-demand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this in the following way

The mid point of the device can be find out this way

X=devicewidth * 0.5

Y=deviceHeight * 0.5

Call 0.5 as heightFactor and widhtFactor

Any other points in the device have its own heightFactor and widhtFactor

We get X and Y value from onTouch event (event.getX() and event.getY())

So to find heightFactor and widhtFactor

heightFactor =X/deviceHeight

widhtFactor=Y/devicewidth

thus we get heightFactor and widhtFactor for each point which will be same for all device

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you really mean with "in different devices the x and y values changed" because if a user touches the screen, the values will change even on same device. You might have a look into [`getRawX()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawX%28%29) and [`getRawY()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawY%28%29) methods. These values are not adjusted the containing window and view.

Comment: Is there any way get unique values for x and y in different devices when user click on same position

Comment: Different devices have different screen sizes and different densities. How do you define same position then?

Answer (score 0):

You can able to find ontouch event,developers.android.com gives a training on this page [find out here](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html)